# ¿Cómo hago una consulta con `WHERE` junto a `AND` en Derby?

Tags: base-de-datos, apache

Estoy luchando con realizar un `UPDATE` en mi base de datos con derby. Por algún motivo, no me quiere funcionar el `AND`.

```
UPDATE TARIFAS SET "IMGHAB"='riu_estandar.jpg' 
WHERE TIPO_HABITACION = 'Estandar' 
AND HOTELES_IDHOTELES = 'M001'
```

Y el mensaje que suelta es el siguiente:

> No se ha encontrado ninguna fila para FETCH, UPDATE o DELETE; o el resultado de una consulta es una tabla vacía.

Si le quito el `AND`, la consulta corre normalmente, pero me edita todas las celdas de la columna, cosa que no deseo. ¿Cómo hago entonces una consulta con `WHERE` junto a `AND` en Derby?

Comment: Si haces un select con las mismas condiciones del where ¿te regresa registros?

Comment: No salen errores, pero me devuelve registros vacios @M.Gress

Comment: Entonces posiblemente no tienes registros que cumplan esa condición y por eso te sale ese error.

Comment: Hmm.... pude resolver el problema graficamente a la final, pero aun me queda esa curiosidad. Dejame verlo mas tarde a fondo y gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que en las bases de datos el orden en que ejecuta una consulta es de atrás haca adelante prueba esto en tu consulta

```
UPDATE TARIFAS SET "IMGHAB"='riu_estandar.jpg' 
WHERE HOTELES_IDHOTELES = 'M001' 
AND TIPO_HABITACION = 'Estandar'
```

lo primero que realizara el motor de la bd sera listar todas la habitaciones que cumplan la condición Estándar después buscara su id y procede a realizar el update